# GTFS - Improving search for trips in two feeds

Tags: java, gtfs

I'm currently working on a java program that takes in two feeds and prints out the trips that are missing in either of the feeds or are partially in it. For example Feed 1 has a trip T1 with the stops ABCDE and Feed 2 has a trip T2 with the stops ABCD. So T2 is a subset of T1.

I basically have one `Map<Type, List<Trip>>` for each feed. The Type is the route type (bus, tram,  etc.) and the `List<Trip>` contains all trips of that type.

All `Trip` objects have the fields that are specified [here](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/trips-file). And also a reference to a `List<StopTime>` and  a `Service` which specifies the stops in sorted order and the service times when the trip is running.

The check works as intended and I get the results I expect. But running time with large feeds (40.000 and more trips) is quite long, because i basically check every trip from one list with the other which would be O(n^2) in the worst case if I'm not mistaken.

I'm looking for a way to minimize the trips I have to look at.
One thing that I could do is to move the check if the date ranges of the trips overlap.This is currently done when checking the `List<StopTime>`within the `Trip` object.

Comment: Your example is not truly reproducible*, but you might give Java 8's ParallelStreams and ConcurrentHashMap a try.

* http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, 
* http://radar.oreilly.com/2015/02/java-8-streams-api-and-parallelism.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know GTFS, however, perhaps you can translate my solution to it.  What I would do is construct a Map like this for the second feed:

```
Map<StopTime, List<Trip>> tripsByStopTime;
```

You can do this by walking through the second feed like this (for example, you can do it any way you like as long as you get the map above) -- since I'm using `StopTime` as a key, make sure it has a proper `equals` and `hashCode`:

```
for (List<Trip> trips : feed2.values()) {
    for (Trip trip : trips) {
        for (StopTime stopTime : trip.getStopTimes()) {
            tripsByStopTime.computeIfAbsent(stopTime, k -> new ArrayList<>())
                 .add(trip);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have this map you can check much quicker for potential matching trips as only trips are considered that have at least one matching stop time (note I'm assuming that the stop time is fairly unique, if most of them are duplicates this approach won't scale well):

```
for (List<Trip> trips : feed1.values()) {
    for (Trip trip : trips) {
        Set<Trip> potentialMatchingTrips = new HashSet<>();

        for (StopTime stopTime : trip.getStopTimes()) {
            List<Trip> list = tripsByStopTime.get(stopTime);

            if (list != null) {
                potentialMatchingTrips.add(list);
            }
        }

        for (Trip potentialMatchingTrip : potentialMatchingTrips) {
              // Check here if it was a subset.
        }
    }
}
```

You can probably write this quite nicely as a stream as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to translate your solution and it works like a charm :)